# OPA engine support for concurrent calls

Tags: open-policy-agent

How many concurrent REST Put/Patch calls can an OPA engine support to update the policy/data?

I tried looking through the documentation, but couldn't find any information pertaining to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPA currently supports multiple concurrent policy queries (which are read-only) and 1 concurrent write (e.g., an HTTP PUT on /v1/data). The reads and write can be processed concurrently. When the write is committed, the server will block until outstanding policy queries complete.